# Python multithreading | send message to specific client

Tags: python-2.7

> I'm trying to send a message to a specific client. I've already made a server that send message to all clients but I don't know how to send message to specific client. ,here's my server code:

**server.py**

```
from socket import *
from codecs import decode
#from chatrecord import ChatRecord
from threading import Thread
from time import ctime

class ClientHandler(Thread):

    def __init__(self,client,address):
        global sockets
        global addresses
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._client = client
        self._address = address
        sockets.append(self._client)
        addresses.append(self._address)

    def run(self):
        self._client.send('Welcome to the chatroom!\n')

        while 1:
            message =self._client.recv(BUFSIZE)
            print '\n\n',sockets
            if not message:
                print "Client disconnected."
                addIndex=sockets.index(self._client)
                del sockets[addIndex]
                del addresses[addIndex]
                self._client.close()
                break
            else:
                if 'ONLINE#' in message:
                    for x in sockets:
                        if (x!=self._client):
                            try:
                                x.send(message[7:])
                            except:
                                print 'disconnected'
                                continue
                    print message[7:]
                else:     
                    for x in sockets:
                        try:
                            x.send(message)
                            /*sockets is the list of all client*/
                        except:
                            print ' '
                            continue
                    print message


HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 1235
ADDRESS = (HOST,PORT)
BUFSIZE = 1024
server = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDRESS)
server.listen(5)
sockets=[]
addresses=[]

while True:
    print "Waiting for connection..."
    client, address = server.accept()
    print('...client connected from: ',address)
    handler = ClientHandler(client,address)
    handler.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this is a chatroom, I would create a dictionary with a nickname for the client when they connect.

client gets prompted with -> pick a name!

client chooses: clientname = jimbob

```py
mydict = {}
mydict[clientname] = self._address
```

then, you can simply get a user by nickname

```py
for client,addr in mydict.iteritems():
   if client == "jimbob":
       destinationaddr = addr
       break
```

it's been a while since I've done python, so you may want to take that as more pseudocode.

You may also want to look up the documentation for [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html)

edit: you will also want to see if that nickname is taken when a client connects. It will be very much like the above for loop, except maybe set a boolean if the user exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. .i have now an idea for sending message on specific client thank for your help